# Using for each in a multiarray in php

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

hello I have the next array and I want to print each id and next to it the path.

```
$data = array('id' => array('1','2','3','4'),
            'path' => array('pathto1', 'pathto2', 'pathto3', 'pathto4')
          );
```

I use foreach for it but I get errors.

```
foreach ($data as $row){
        echo $row['id']." ".$row['path']."<br/>";
    }
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: this one Undefined index: id
         Undefined index: path

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Comment: $row will have value of `array('1','2','3','4')` not`id`

Comment: Why don't you use the array key as id. if you have `$a=array(0,'pathto1','pathto2');` you could use `$a[$id]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your array filled in wrong. It should be:

```
$data = array(array('id' => 1, path => 'pathto1'),
              array('id' => 2, path => 'pathto2'),
              array('id' => 3, path => 'pathto3'),
              array('id' => 4, path => 'pathto4'),
             );
```

With this, your loop will work. To use your existing array, it would be:

```
foreach ($data['id'] as $index => $id) {
    echo $id." ".$data['path'][$index]."<br/>";
}
```

I generally recommend fixing the array structure. It's best to keep all the related data together in a sub-array, rather than trying to keep parallel arrays in sync.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($data['id'] as $key=>$id){
    echo $id.' '.$data['path'][$key].'<br>';
}
```

It would be easier if you constructed the original array as:

```
 array(1=>'pathto1', 2=>'pathto2', etc...);
```

Then you could do

```
foreach($row AS $key=>$value){
   echo $key.' '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Your first loop looks wrong. `$id = 1` matches `$data['path'][0]`.

Comment: Good call @Barmar, fixed it.

Comment: What if the IDs aren't consecutive?

Comment: What if? Did you see my fix? ;)

Comment: I wrote it before that fix.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` loops over all elements, giving you either the element, or its key and value as local variables:

In your case:

```
foreach ($data as $row){
    // $row first holds array('1', '2','3','4')
    // in the second loop it holds array('pathto1', ..., 'pathto4')
}
```

if you also want the keys, you can do:

```
foreach ($data as $key=>$row){
    // $row first holds array('1', '2','3','4'), $key holds "id"
    // in the second loop $row holds array('pathto1', ..., 'pathto4') 
    //       and $key holds "path"   
}
```

To get whay you want, you need another way of defining your array (as @Barmar suggests), and your `foreach` will work fine.